# how can i print a 21x42cm picture on a "custom" 21x42cm paper without getting it shrink to (A4) 21x30cm?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

from Gimp 2,10.22 on Ubuntu 21.04 GNU/Linux, i'm trying to print a 21x42cm picture on a 21x42cm custom paper size, but in the end it gets printed shrink ("distorting" pixel ratio) in the 21x30cm beginning of the printing area, leaving the remaining area totally blank

i was expecting only having the paper margins unprinted, that wouldn't be larger than 1.5cm, but the lowest part gets larger than 12cm

the printer is an Epson ET2710 "ecotank"

thanks and cheers,
Paulo

Comment: Put he picture in LibreOffice Writer and print from there.

Comment: SureColor *T2170* 24-Inch printer : You can export from GIMP → to png or jpg image . And then print to any size in e.g. **Gwenview**.